# Round to nearest and least multiple of 10

Tags: php, laravel

So here is my situation. I have a couple of numbers where I want to round to the nearest and least multiple of 10.

For example values in between 51 to 59 should round to 50.

```
Input = 59 = >Respose = 50

Input = 51 => Respose = 50
```

I have tried

```
$number = round(53, -1);
```

which will gives be 50 which is correct which I want, but if I try with 56, it will give me 60. But here also, am expecting 50. Can somebody help me out?

> Accepted answer (In case some one is reading the question)

floor($number / 10)*10

However ,it gives be decimal values which I round and changed to

```
$amount = (int)floor($amount / 10)*10;
```

Comment: `floor($number / 10)*10` ? The use of the word "round" is misleading. You need to `floor` it.

Comment: @apokryfos thanks. it works

Comment: @apokryfos: Although flooring is a rounding technique.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, typically one would say "round down (floor)" or "round up (ceil)" or "round to nearest (round)" but the wording here is "round to nearest and least" which is a very uncommon way of putting it.

Answer (score 7):

Use `floor` instead; first dividing by 10 then multiplying the truncated result back up:

`$number = floor($number / 10) * 10`

Using solutions such as `$number = round($number - 5, -1);` can cause you problems with floating point edge cases. (Interestingly that's how early Java implementations did it, with disastrous results.)

Answer (score 6):

**Round down:**

```
$x = floor($x/10) * 10;
```

**Round up:**

```
$x = ceil($x/10) * 10;
```

**Round to closest (up or down):**

```
$x = round($x/10) * 10;
```

Comment: Although `round` does have that extra parameter, which obviates the /10 *10 part.

Comment: round() will round to the nearest integer using standard rounding rules..

Comment: i think using modulus operator is more elegant in this situation..   echo $value - ($value % 10);

Comment: **Don't** use `$value - ($value % 10);`: you'll hit floating point edge cases,

Answer (score 2):

You have to divide your number by `10`, then [floor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) it, then multiply by 10 :

```
<?php

function floor10($input) {
    $input = $input/10;
    $input = floor($input);
    $input = 10*$input;
    return $input;
}

echo floor10(51); // echoes 50
echo floor10(59); // echoes 50
```

Answer (score 0):

use int to remove decimal points after devide and then mul by 10
(int)($num/10)*10

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any function for this its simple math.

```
/* rating percentage to nearest 10 */
$rating_percentage=92; //if 92 output will be 90

$r=$rating_percentage%10; //get the remainder after dividing by number 10
$rating_percentage=$rating_percentage-$r; //deduct the remainder to make the number perfectly dividible by 10 
$r=$r>=5?10:0; //if remainder is greater or equal to 5 make it 10 else 0
$rating_percentage=$rating_percentage+$r;//add the updated remainder back to number


print_r("<pre>");
print_r($rating_percentage); //output 90 for 91-94 and 100 for 96-100
print_r("</pre>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete function, UP, DOWN or ROUND to any number

```
function roundNumber($num, $to, $dir = null)
{
    if ($dir === 'down') {
        return floor($num / $to) * $to;
    } else if ($dir === 'up') {
        return ceil($num / $to) * $to;
    } else {
        return round($num / $to) * $to;
    }
}
```

Examples

```
echo roundNumber(104, 5);
// 105

echo roundNumber(102, 5);
// 100

echo roundNumber(104, 5, 'up');
// 105

echo roundNumber(104, 5, 'down');
// 100


echo roundNumber(115, 10);
// 120

echo roundNumber(114, 10);
// 110

echo roundNumber(113, 10, 'up');
// 120

echo roundNumber(113, 10, 'down');
// 110
```